# Why does this MultiDataTrigger throw an exception on animation?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

A WPF-MVVM application that displays multiple views on a viewmodel. The user can go from less detailed to more detailed view at run time. The views are contained within a border. Under a set of conditions, an alarm is triggered by the viewmodel. The alarm is rendered in the view as an animation of flashing color on the border background to attract user attention.

The problem is that when the alarm is triggered AND user changes datatemplates during run time to get more detail, the WPF engine throws an exception on animation when using a multidatatrigger alarm. The engine works when using a Datatrigger and crashes on MultiDataTrigger with everything else the same.

The exception is: Cannot animate '(0).(1)' on an immutable object

A sample application to demonstrate issue:

1 MainWindow for hosting and toggling views.

2 views, large and small.

1 viewmodel.

1 Resource dictionary for the multi and single datatriggers

App.Xaml:

```
<Application x:Class="AnimationSample.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AnimationSample"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml"/>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="AnimationSample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AnimationSample"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SampleViewModel}" x:Key="smallTemplate">
            <local:SmallUserControl />
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SampleViewModel}" x:Key="largeTemplate">
            <local:LargeUserControl />
        </DataTemplate>        
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:SampleViewModel}" x:Key="mainTemplate">
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ZoomSlider, Path=Value}" Value="1">                 
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource smallTemplate}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ZoomSlider, Path=Value}" Value="2">                        
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource largeTemplate}"/>
                </DataTrigger>                
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}" x:Key="DisplayStyle">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource smallTemplate}" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ZoomSlider, Path=Value}" Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource smallTemplate}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=ZoomSlider, Path=Value}" Value="2">
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource largeTemplate}"/>
                </DataTrigger>                
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <StackPanel Margin="8">
        <Slider x:Name="ZoomSlider" Minimum="1" Maximum="2" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True" />
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource DisplayStyle}">
        </ContentControl>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.cs:

```
using System.Windows;

namespace AnimationSample
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new SampleViewModel();
        }
    }
}
```

SampleViewModel.cs:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Windows;

namespace AnimationSample
{
    public class SampleViewModel : NotifyPropertyChangedBase<SampleViewModel>
    {
        private bool _alarm;
        public bool Alarm
        {
            get { return _alarm; }
            set
            {
                if (!_alarm.Equals(value))
                {
                    _alarm = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Alarm");                    
                }
            }
        }

        private bool _flash;
        public bool Flash
        {
            get { return _flash; }
            set
            {
                if (!_flash.Equals(value))
                {
                    _flash = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Flash");
                }
            }
        }


        private string _description = "I am an alarm!";
        public string Description
        {
            get { return _description; }
            set
            {
                if(!_description.Equals(value))
                {
                    _description = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged("Description");
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public abstract class NotifyPropertyChangedBase<T> : DependencyObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            { PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName)); }
        }

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged<T2>(Expression<Func<T, T2>> accessor)
        {
            OnPropertyChanged(PropertyName(accessor));
        }        

        public static string PropertyName<T2>(Expression<Func<T, T2>> accessor)
        {
            return ((MemberExpression)accessor.Body).Member.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

Dictionary1.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AnimationSample">
    <Style x:Key="FlashyAlarmBorderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Silver"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />
        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="8" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Alarm}" Value="True" />
                    <Condition Binding="{Binding Flash}" Value="True" />
                </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Orange"/>
                <MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Name="faultBoard">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation AutoReverse="True" 
                                                RepeatBehavior="Forever" 
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                                                Duration="00:00:01"                                            
                                                From="Silver"
                                                To="Orange"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="faultBoard">
                    </StopStoryboard>
                </MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
            </MultiDataTrigger>
            <!--<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Alarm}" Value="True" >
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Orange"/>
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <BeginStoryboard Name="alarmBoard">
                        <Storyboard>
                            <ColorAnimation AutoReverse="True" 
                                                RepeatBehavior="Forever" 
                                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                                                Duration="00:00:01"                                            
                                                From="Silver"
                                                To="Orange"/>
                        </Storyboard>
                    </BeginStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="alarmBoard">
                    </StopStoryboard>
                </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
            </DataTrigger>-->          
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

LargeUserControl.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="AnimationSample.LargeUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AnimationSample"
             mc:Ignorable="d" >
    <Border Margin="8"
            Style="{DynamicResource FlashyAlarmBorderStyle}">
        <StackPanel>
            <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="LARGE VIEW" Foreground="White"/>
            <CheckBox Margin="8" IsChecked="{Binding Alarm}" Content="Turn on the alarm." Foreground="White" />
            <CheckBox Margin="8"  IsChecked="{Binding Flash}" Content="Turn on the flash!" Foreground="White" />
            <Label Margin="8" Content="{Binding Description}" Foreground="White"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

SmallUserControl.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="AnimationSample.SmallUserControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:AnimationSample"
             mc:Ignorable="d" >
    <Border Margin="8"
            Style="{DynamicResource FlashyAlarmBorderStyle}">
        <StackPanel>
            <Label HorizontalAlignment="Center" Content="SMALL VIEW" Foreground="White"/>
            <CheckBox Margin="4" IsChecked="{Binding Alarm}" Content="Turn on the alarm." HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" />
            <CheckBox Margin="4" IsChecked="{Binding Flash}" Content="Turn on the flash!" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" />
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

If you run the code and click on the alarm and flash checkboxes, then the control will go from silver border with black background to a flashing orange. If you move the slider to go from small to large view, you will get a run time from wpf if using the multidatatrigger. If you uncomment the datatrigger in the the Dictionar1.xaml and comment the multidatatrigger, then repeat the above, the application runs ok.

Why does this multidatatrigger gag on DataTemplate change and datatrigger work ok? The only difference from that to the single datatrigger is one extra boolean. How can it be fixed?

(Yes, can work around by creating a property on the viewmodel to aggregate these booleans, but that should not have to be done and is beside question. This seems like a bug with wpf?)

Comment: What is the Exception?

Comment: Cannot animate '(0).(1)' on an immutable object

Answer (score 0):

Remove the setter that sets the same property (`Background`) that you try to animate:

```
<MultiDataTrigger>
    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Binding="{Binding Alarm}" Value="True" />
        <Condition Binding="{Binding Flash}" Value="True" />
    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
    <!--<Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange"/>-->
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Orange"/>
    <MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
        <BeginStoryboard Name="faultBoard">
            <Storyboard>
                <ColorAnimation AutoReverse="True" 
                                RepeatBehavior="Forever" 
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" 
                                Duration="00:00:01"                                            
                                From="Silver"
                                To="Orange"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
    <MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
        <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="faultBoard">
        </StopStoryboard>
    </MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
</MultiDataTrigger>
```

Comment: It does for me.

Comment: You are right! Not sure what I was smoking...Thanks for the review!